# React image doesn't show up

Tags: reactjs

I have this project and although that I use `require()` method, and photos show up in vscode but on the localhost it doesn't show up. my folder tree is:

```
.
├── app.js
├── components
│   ├── board
│   │   └── Board.jsx
│   ├── card
│   │   ├── Card.jsx
│   │   ├── ExpDiv.jsx
│   │   └── ImDiv.jsx
│   └── navbar
│       ├── Navbar.jsx
│       └── navbar.css
├── data
│   └── data.js
├── images
│   ├── forest_walk_dabiediedu.jpg
│   ├── forest_walk_dabiediedu_winter.jpg
│   ├── killer_monkey_insta.jpg
│   ├── mushroom_giant.jpg
│   └── running_batbeast.jpg
├── index.js
└── pages
    ├── About.js
    ├── Contacts.js
    ├── Drawings.js
    └── Main.js
```

and data/data.js:

```
export const dataJson = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "forest_walk_dabiediedu_winter.jpg",
        src: "src/images/forest_walk_dabiediedu_winter.jpg",
        explanation: "dabie is one of the craziest creatures i've ever created. " +
            "His ambition to find the infinity stones will lead him to the " +
            "his lost family.",
        alt: "my monster dabie in snow"
    },
    .
    .
    .
```

all the src's are like: `src/images/... .jpg`

the screenshot of the screen is:
[image]

I used card component, with `<ImageDiv>` and `ExplanationDiv`:

Card.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { ImageDiv } from "./ImDiv";
import { ExplanationDiv } from "./ExpDiv";

function Card(props) {
    return (
        <div key={props.id}>
            <ImageDiv src={props.src} alt={props.alt}/>
            <ExplanationDiv text={props.text}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

ImDiv.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const ImDiv = styled.div`
    background-color: grey;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 5rem;
    height: 20rem;
    padding-top: 2.2rem;
`;

const Img = styled.img`
    width: 85%;
    height: auto;
`;

export function ImageDiv(props) {
    return (
        <ImDiv>
            <Img src={props.src} alt={props.alt}/>
        </ImDiv>
    );
};
```

and ExplanationDiv:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const ExpDiv = styled.div`
    padding-top: 1rem;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
`;

export function ExplanationDiv(props) {
    return (
        <ExpDiv>
            <p>{props.text}</p>
        </ExpDiv>
    );
};

export default ExpDiv;
```

thank you guys.

Comment: I'd suggest hosting them from your public folder

Comment: hey, which files you mean?

Comment: Sorry I mean the images. Those can be served from your public folder. If you will need an image loader if you want to include them as part of your build process I think.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the path of the img.

Try this :

```
export const dataJson = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: "forest_walk_dabiediedu_winter.jpg",
    src: "../../images/forest_walk_dabiediedu_winter.jpg",
    explanation: "dabie is one of the craziest creatures i've ever created. " +
        "His ambition to find the infinity stones will lead him to the " +
        "his lost family.",
    alt: "my monster dabie in snow"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying what Micky said, i moved the images folder inside the public folder. and after changing the path like this:

```
export const dataJson = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: "forest_walk_dabiediedu_winter.jpg",
    src: "../images/forest_walk_dabiediedu_winter.jpg",
    explanation: "dabie is one of the craziest creatures i've ever created. " +
        "His ambition to find the infinity stones will lead him to the " +
        "his lost family.",
    alt: "my monster dabie in snow"
},
```

it worked.